# Help Calculating Computer Time used by Algorithms

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Recently I have been working through a textbook question that states the following:

> An algorithm takes 0.5 ms for input size 100. How long will it take
>   for input size 500 (assuming that low-order terms are negligible) if
>   the running time is
>
> a. linear
>
> b. O(N log N )
>
> c. quadratic
>
> d. cubic

Now I know how to get Linear as $500/100 = 5$ thus $0.5ms * 5 = 2.5ms$

What I don't understand is how do I scale this answer of 2.5ms linearly to quadratic, nlogn, and cubic? Are there theorems or expressions that I am missing?

The way I would go about $N^2$ is that $2.5ms^2 $ is 6.25 ms which is not the answer in the answer key(ans = 12.5). and i'm not sure what I would start with for $nlogn$

What does it mean when the question says this?

> (assuming that low-order terms are negligible)

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say that an algorithm runs in $O(N \log(N))$ that means that there exists a constant $C$ such that the time of execution $T(n)$ (as a function of the size $n$ of the input) is such that $T(n) \leq C n \log(n)$. And this is not very precise. Often we implicitly mean that the algorithm runs in $\Theta(N \log(N))$, which means that there exists two constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that $C_1 n \log(n) \leq T(n) \leq C_2 n \log(n)$.

That being said, to answer your question we will consider that the running time of your algorithm is $T(n)=C n \log(n)$.

Then $T(500)= 500C \log(500)$ and $T(100)=100C\log(100)$. Then $100C=\dfrac{T(100)}{\log(100)}$.

You get that $$T(500)=5 (100C) \log(500) = 5 \dfrac{\log(500)}{\log(100)}T(100)\approx 5 \cdot 1.35 \cdot T(100) = 6.75 \cdot T(100) = 3.4 \textrm{ms}$$

For the other complexities the computations are easier:

- quadratic: $T(n) = C n^2$ gives $$\dfrac{T(500)}{T(100)}=\dfrac{(500^2)}{100^2}=5^2=25$$ Then $T(500)=25 \cdot 0.5 = 12.5 \textrm{ms}$
- cubic: $T(n) = C n^3$ gives $$\dfrac{T(500)}{T(100)}=\dfrac{(500^3)}{100^3}=5^3=125$$ Then $T(500)=125 \cdot 0.5 = 62.5 \textrm{ms}$

Of course these values are only approximations and only give a rough idea of the running time you can expect.

Comment: Your answer explains a lot about how to approach this question, thanks. I Just have one more question. Could you go a bit more in depth in your nlogn example. How does $T(500) = 500Clog(500)$ turn into $T(500)=5log(500)T(100)/log(100)$ ? and how does that get you 1.35? do we divide the log(500) by log(100) somehow?

Comment: @BigChemist I edited my answer to make it clearer. You have to replace $100C$ by $T(100)/\log(100)$. And the 1.35 is indeed obtained as $\log(500)/\log(100)$

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up. Just to check my understanding...  When we reached $T(500) = 5(T100/log100) log(500)$ are we aloud to just swap $log(500)$ with $T100$ because they are on the same level in the equation? or is there a different reason?

Comment: yeah, you have $a \dfrac{b}{c}d=\dfrac{a\cdot b \cdot d}{c}=a\dfrac{d}{c}b$

Comment: Perfect, I was thinking in addition not multiplication, duh. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

(*Too long for a comment*.) The answer posted already is likely what the problem asks for, yet it may be worth noting that the question itself is ill defined, because the asymptotic behavior does *not* dictate what happens for small numbers like $100$ or $500\,$.

The reason why polynomial behaviors can be estimated with some confidence is that the result depends *only* on the ratio of the input sizes. If the input grows $5$ times larger, then the time will grow $5^1, 5^2, 5^3$ larger for linear, quadratic and cubic behaviors, respectively.

In contrast, if the input $N$ grows $5$ times larger with $\mathcal{O}(N \log N)$ behavior, then the time will grow by $\,5 \cdot \log(5N) / \log(N) = 5 \cdot\left(1 + \log(5) / \log(N)\right)\,$ which is a function that depends on $N\,$. Consider for example that the input of $100$ is a weight measured in grams ($\text{g}$). Then the time to process $500\,\text{g}$ would calculate to $\,0.5 \cdot 5 \cdot \log(500) / \log(100) \simeq \color{red}{3.37 \,\text{ms}}\,$. However, the same weight measured in kilograms ($\text{kg}$) is $100\,\text{g} = 0.1\,\text{kg}\,$, and the time to process $500\,\text{g} = 0.5\,\text{kg}\,$ would come out to be $\,0.5 \cdot 5 \cdot \log(0.5) / \log(0.1) \simeq \color{red}{0.75 \,\text{ms}}\,$, instead. The two estimates are far apart, though the actual time to process a given weight would obviously be the same, regardless of whether it's measured in grams or kilograms.

Comment: This is a good point to make, and it's another way to look at the question in the bigger picture.